# iptables forward tcp port to another port on same host after connection already established

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

i have a tcp server that prints messages it gets(without sending back) on port 1234 and another tcp server on port 5678. i have a client that already communicates with the 1234 server and i want to redirect it to the 5678 server.

i know how to redirect packet (with the connection request)
`ip tables -t nat -I PREROUTING  -p tcp --dport 1234 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5678`
but it not works if the connection already established on previous server, my question is how to enforce reconnection without the client to hang

Comment: If a *different* connection from the same client (ie: different source port) happens this won't alter the established connection and the new one(s) will be redirected. If you wanted to alter the established connection, supposing you had a way to do this, this wouldn't work for TCP because it's a connection-oriented protocol which keeps connection state. For UDP there could be options, but all of this doesn't make sense to me until you give a concrete example explaining what you want to do with an example and especially *why* you want to do it.

Comment: @A.B i want to scan payload of a tcp connection(data that goes to some server on my machine) and drop packets that contain the word "hello" in it.

Comment: Edit your question to clarify it. Dropping isn't redirecting. Anyway redirecting probably not possible with iptables for TCP.